# Printing Theorem in Orange

Tags: theorems

I think that `latex` without `ams` does supply the theorem environment.  I would like to make my own commands based on the built-in theorem functionality without using the `ams` tools package, so I can write the theorem name in colour.  What can I do?

For instance, I would like "Definition" to be printed in orange.  I would also like `\theorem` to print "Theorem" in orange as well.

```
\newtheorem{lexdefinition}{Definition}[section]
```

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using `amsthm` and running `\newtheorem{lexdefinition}{\textcolor{orange}{Definition}}[section]` along with `\let\oldthelexdef\thelexdefinition \renewcommand\thelexdefinition{\textcolor{orange}{\oldthelexdef}}`?

Comment: I want to build separate from `ams`, building from the most basic latex built-in.  But I would be fine taking basic code from `ams` and use colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\color` instead of `\textcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheorem{definition}{\color{orange}Definition}

\newtheorem{definitionnormal}{Definition}

\begin{document}

Some text preceding the definition.

\begin{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

Some text in the middle.

\begin{definitionnormal}
A definition.
\end{definitionnormal}

Some text to end the test.

\end{document}
```

I defined another environment just to see that the output is the same, except for the coloring.

[image]